# What is the optimum packet (query) size for a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I know from varying sources around the web, that I can set the max_allowed_packet upto 1GB, but by default is usually 16MB.

My question is what is the optimum size for a packet (query)? I often break very large queries into smaller chunks, of say 5 or 10 MB, but is there an optimum size or is it a case of the bigger, the quicker?

Note, this is using the mysql command line utility, not any programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be more concerned about execution time and the impact on other operations than the query size itself. Usually you do larger queries to restore from back-ups and the processing time isn't as much of an issue.

The only way to know how it is in your instance is to benchmark it.

Comment: I've benchmarked it and it seems to be the larger the query, the quicker it runs, although it does lock the database up for longer meaning nothing else can access it.

Comment: As long as you don't block for "too long", which is a subjective thing, then you should go for the biggest possible query.